# PANDAS coarse dates (month/year)

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Say I'm looking at the Rdataset acme.csv found [here](http://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/boot/acme.csv). How do I import this with appropriately coarse date? Using parse_dates, it assigns the day to the present day (today being the 18th of July), since no day was specified. Can I make it deal with just month/year like the table is but keep using the date functionality of PANDAS?

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'http://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/boot/acme.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=[1])
df.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: You could add few rows from that file and expecte result.

Comment: there's no way to have a month.  You will always have a day as well

Comment: BTW: you can use two columns - first with date as `datetime` (to use its functionality`), second with date as string `m/y` (to show in results`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't parse dates in `read_csv()` but use `to_datetime` with `format`

```
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month'], format='%m/%y')
```

or you can use that function in `read_csv()` using lambda

```
df = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=['month'], date_parser=lambda x:pd.to_datetime(x, format='%m/%y'))
```

But you always get some day number in `datetime`.

**BTW:** In `datetime` you have always `time` too, but sometimes pandas doesn't show it.

```
print df['month'].head()
print df['month'].apply(lambda x:x.time()).head()
```